# How can I add a click button cycle URL function (that flips between urls in given order) to this script or is it possible?

Tags: javascript, url, button, click, rotator

How can I add a click button cycle URL function (that cycles between urls in given order) to this script or is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "facebook.com";
urls[1] = "yahoo.com";
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
window.location = urls[random];

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want that when you click the button, you are directed to the new url?

Comment: So it redirects to each url in turn?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it "rotate" or "cycle" in this fashion because once you set the `window.location` to a new location, the page with this script on it is no longer running in the browser.

You would need to setup a frame that controls another frame in order to accomplish this. Then you could update the contents of the target frame. Also note that using `random()` is not making the urls show in sequence either.